# constant expression required in switch with string

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, constant-expression

I have declared this enum class:

```
public enum class RoleName {
    Worker,
    Boss
}
```

which I want to use it in a switch / case

```
switch (requestRole.getName()) {
    case RoleName.Worker.name():
```

but I have this compilation error

```
constant expression required
```

and if I remove `class` I got this IntelliJ IDEA error: `'class' keyword is expected after 'enum;`

Comment: `enum` not `enum class`

Comment: change your RoleName.Worker.name() to "Worker"

Comment: Is that really the error message you get when removing `class`? Exactly these words?

Comment: Are you trying to turn a string containing the name of an `RoleName` constant into the actual `RoleName` object?

Comment: @Sandro I saw you asked another question on this issue and deleted it, feel free to ask what remains unclear here - I'll update my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two mistakes here:

1. The definition of the enum shouldn't have `class` in it. As a rule of thumb, the constants should be uppercase.

   ```
   enum RoleName {
       WORKER,
       BOSS;
   }
   ```
2. `RoleName.Worker.name()` isn't allowed as a `case` expression since it's not [a constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-ConstantExpression). You could transform `requestRole.getName()` into a `RoleName` and use it as [a `switch` expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11).

   ```
   switch (RoleName.valueOf(requestRole.getName())) {
       case WORKER: /* ... */ break;
   }
   ```

Comment: #2 is not exactly the same code, because if value of `requestRole.getName()` doesn't match an enum name, then question code will work (go to `default` if any), and this code will throw `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: I spent looking for a valid DUP candidate ... but hey, all of these questions are slightly different. Go make this the DUP candidate for switch case calling a method!

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger because `requestRole` isn't a `RoleName`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger `getName` isn't a enum method

Comment: It’s actually `case WORKER:`.  Java doesn’t allow qualified enum constants in `case` statements.